# TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation

Tags: machine-learning, python, training, computer-vision

I have one dataset containing images X of type ( numpy array) and one target csv file as Y which has counts of cells (type : pandas dataframe, that I have converted to numpy array), both are now read as numpy arrays. Essentially, I am creating a training dataset to train my images with target dataset using cnn model.

For the code below i am getting an error that argument is bad.

Any help on how to solve this?

```
                    **image = cv2.imread(img_path)**
```

Full code:

```
def load_data():
    
    import os

    datasets =  (X,Y)
    
    
    images = []
    labels = []

    # iterate through training and test sets
    count =0
    for dataset in datasets:

        # iterate through folders in each dataset
        for folder in dataset:

                    if folder in ['plasma']: label = 'T4'
                    elif folder in ['lymphocyte']: label = 'T3'
                    elif folder in ['epithelial']: label = 'T2'
                    elif folder in ['neutrophil']: label = 'T1'
                    elif folder in ['eosinophil']: label = 'T5'
                    elif folder in ['connective']: label = 'T6'

                    img_path = np.append(dataset, folder)
                    **image = cv2.imread(img_path)**
                    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                
                # resize the image
                    image = cv2.resize(image, image_size)

                # Append the image and its corresponding label to the output
                    images.append(image)
                    labels.append(label)


                


                    images = np.array(images, dtype = 'float32')
                    labels = np.array(labels, dtype = 'int32')

    return images, labels
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-a8d2a3fd920f> in <module>
----> 1 images, labels = load_data()

<ipython-input-144-1acddd84d1e7> in load_data()
     24 
     25                     img_path = np.append(dataset, folder)
---> 26                     image = cv2.imread(img_path)
     27                     image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
     28 

TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defintion cv2.imread() expect the path: A string representing the path of the image to be read. The image should be in the working directory or a full path of image should be given

Unclear on your datasets structure and what are you keeping inside.

Still at this line `img_path = np.append(dataset, folder)`
img_path is an array ( np.append will return an array ) and cannot be passed to the imread() function which is clear from the error (

> bad argument type for built-in operation

)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Is there any other way to read the two (datasets and folder )together, without using the paths or directory?

Comment: Can you update the question with datasets structure and example

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Still not clear on the Dataset structure ( share 1, or 2 rows from X and Y  or a reproducable code so that we can fix the issues.) .  Assuming you are trying to construct the path using dataset and folder , try this image_path = os.path.join(dataset, folder).

Comment: Here, X is a matrix containing N 256x256x3  images of size 256x256 pixels and Y is an Nx6 matrix with each row corresponding to a single image patch and each column corresponding to the 6 types of cells.

With os.path.join, getting this error:

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray

Comment: so Y contain a single image path right ? . Ideally you should be passing that path to the imread() function right . Sorry  , but can you share 2,3 rows from  X and Y